Swapping Old Cooper Turn-Knob Dimmer
I live in a 1960's home and I am slowly trying to make small home upgrades to modernize the home a bit - I have this old Cooper Turn-Knob Dimmer but I can't seem to figure out some things, so wanted to ask around to see if anyone knows the following questions:

How do you properly pop the cap off that has the electrical wires? I have tried using pliers and attempting to push those small gold circle rings in and out with no luck.

Looks like there are two black wires, typically when I swapped outlets we have a white and black wire, positive and negative - How can I determine which black wire goes w/ gold/silver.

Would that Lutron be a possible direct swap? The Cooper is showing 120v on the dimmer.







A picture showing the wires in the box will help.  Are those black wires connected with wire nuts inside the box?  If not, just turn off the breaker and snip near the switch.

They are, I'm now looking to see how I can get to the wire nuts since the cap doesn't pop off.

You turn the circuit breaker off or pull the fuse, pull the wires out of the box in the wall, and untwist the wirenuts. Or hire an electrician.

If there is no wire nuts on the black wires, then with the power off, just cut the wires close as possible to the switch.

You don't take the cap off the back of the old dimmer.  You remove the wire nuts that connect the wires from the old dimmer to the wiring in the electrical box. Carefully keep track of "which wire went where" with labels and better pictures before disassembly) coming out of that device, one of which is just barely visible in one picture.
There is no positive and negative with the AC house wiring. You will have a live (or hot) and neutral.
A dimmer is a switch. It does not (or should not, depending who has worked on it in the past this may be "not as true as it should be" but you can correct that) switch the neutral wire, though some "smart" switches may now use one to power themselves. A switch has "always hot" and "switched hot." The connection to neutral is made at the other side of the light being switched. Some switches have additional connection so that multiple switches can control one fixture or set of lights. This does not appear to be one.

House wiring is something that can be done safely if you understand it. Not understanding it can kill you directly or result in a fire. Attempting it without understanding it is unwise.

I couldn't agree more, but I have switched out over 10+ outlets without issues, this one is just different - I'm not an electrician, so the terms are something that I don't physically care too much for, but I know that one is live and one is not, typically the black wire is live and in this case, I have two black wires. You post DEFINITELY helps a lot from an educational standpoint.

To the OP: don’t take it too hard, but there is absolutely a learning curve with electricity. When folks here see someone appearing to fundamentally misunderstand, alarm bells go off and the intent is to keep you from electrocuting yourself. Tough but fair in my opinion; you’re free to disagree.

Outlets are different than switches. Outlets connect a hot and a neutral to appliances. The polarized outlets have a silver terminal for the neutral and a brass terminal for the hot.
Single switches normally just make or break a hot connection. You don't touch the neutral unless the switch calls for one. Remove the wire nuts from the two wires and connect them to the red and black wires from your new switch. Since there's only one switch, you won't need the blue wire from the switch so wire nut it. There won't be a gold/silver terminals on this switch and it will pretty much be a direct swap.

